# Making Gaussians Constrained by the FWHM

Tags: python, matplotlib, gaussian

Firstly my maths is limited, so this question may have a simple answer. So, I am using the following equation to make guassian distributions:

```
height * np.exp( - ((x-mean)/width)**2 )
```

When I make gussians with the above equation where is the width of the peak applied? Is it at full width half maximum? I made the following gaussian with the following values:

```
height = 5
mean = 100
width = 10
```

[image]

When I then calculate the FWHM it is `16.6510941453` so the peak width cannot be applied at the FWHM. Where is it applied?

I am trying to constrain the FWHM so the FWHM is 10x smaller than that of the mean. So in the above example I would of liked the gaussian to have a FWHM of 10 at the mean of 100 at a peak height of 5.

Comment: The formula for the [gaussian distribution is here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/5/6/6/56652af13ee737d64cb8cafdd9a53af0.png). Sigma is the standard deviation. Mu is the mean. Solve for f() = 0.5Mu and that will give you your answer

Comment: isnt Mu the centre point of the peak?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I meant solve for x for 0.5*f(Mu)

Comment: There is a nice wikipedia article on FWHM that you might find useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your equation, the width parameter is actually `sigma`, which is the standard deviation of a Gaussian, not FWHM.  Below are functions to convert between the two of these properties

```
from numpy import sqrt, log

def sigma2Gamma(sigma):
    '''Function to convert standard deviation (sigma) to FWHM (Gamma)'''
    return sigma * sqrt(2 * log(2)) * 2 / sqrt(2)

Gamma = sigma2Gamma(10)
print Gamma
# prints 16.651092223153956, which is what you saw in your graph

def Gamma2sigma(Gamma):
    '''Function to convert FWHM (Gamma) to standard deviation (sigma)'''
    return Gamma * sqrt(2) / ( sqrt(2 * log(2)) * 2 )

sigma = Gamma2sigma(10)
print sigma
# prints 6.0056120439322491, which is the standard deviation that will
# give a FWHM of 10
```

I would recommend changing your equation to

```
height * np.exp( - ((x-mean)/Gamma2sigma(width))**2 )
```

if you want to input the FWHM and not the standard deviation